# Need to change date into current work week (1-52), but skip to the next week if the day is Wed - Sat in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm having trouble writing code in VBA that would allow me to input any given date then have an output of the current work week.  I need a restriction of if the date is Sunday through Tuesday, it will keep that current work week and year but if the date is Wednesday through Saturday, then the next work week and year will show.  For example, I'm looking to input (5/28/19) and have an output of 201922 or an input of (5/29/19) with an output of 201923 even though its technically the same work week.

Before getting too in depth, I do have a working function that provides the year and work week, but I'm trying to adapt the function or add a separate function that will change in to the next work week according to the given date.

I'm new to VBA but have tried to do a little research over the last few days.  I was thinking that I could somehow have one input of the date then have two outputs where one would be the year and work week then the other would be the number associated with that date (1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, and so on).  I tried to create an if then statement that says if the number associated with that date is 1, 2, or 3 then the workweek would stay the same.  If it was any other number then 1 would be added to that work week so it would move to the next one.  I'm having trouble with trying to make two outputs and have them connected, if that makes any sense.

This is the code that I tried to create, but continuously failed at making. The function that gives the correct work week (without the adaptation of the work week based on the date weekday) is WWV1

```
Function WWV2(WeekdayName As Integer)


Dim WWV1 As Integer

If WeekdayName(Date) = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Then WWV1 = WWV1

Else: WWV1 = WWV1 + 1


End Function
```

This provides the cell with #NUM! when I use the function in that cell, which I assume is because I need to somehow connect the two functions.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
=YEAR(A1) & TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1,13),"00")
```

WeekNum returns the weeknumber with `13` saying it starts on Wednesday:

[image]

---

VBA

```
 wkcd = Year(Range("A1")) & Format(Application.WeekNum(Range("A1")),"00")
```

Comment: This definitely works, but do you know how I could produce this in VBA?